# Needs to uncheck sysadmin role of domain user in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce, database-administration

We've established connections between SQL Server views and Excel, utilizing pivot tables within Excel sheets for data analysis. Recently, we were directed to modify the sysadmin server role of a domain user. However, encountering an obstacle emerged when we attempted to revoke the sysadmin role from the domain user – following this action, the Excel report ceased to refresh. The requirement is for the Excel report to refresh even without the sysadmin role, presenting a challenge in this scenario

Comment: Clearly the user, therefore, lacks permissions to do what they need to do, such as having a mapped `USER` in the database, or `SELECT` on the table(s), etc.